# Building with resx resource files included in the output

Tags: azure, azure-devops, resx, msbuild-task, .net-4.7.2

I have two `.NET Framework` solutions, each with a `\Resources` folder containing `resx` files of the format `strings.cs-CZ.resx`.

One solution is built on Azure DevOps with the [Visual Studio build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vsbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) step having these `MSBuild Arguments`:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:PublishProfile="$(build.sourcesdirectory)\App.Api\Properties\PublishProfiles\VSTS-InPlacePublish.pubxml"
```

The build pipeline produces an artefact containing a `\Resources` folder with all the `.resx` files from the solution.

The second solution is built on Azure DevOps with the same [Visual Studio build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vsbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) step, but having these `MSBuild Arguments`:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\App\\"
```

This build pipeline artefact does not contain a `\Resources` folder at all, and is completely missing any `.resx` files.

I am reading the various articles about `msbuild` and it's switches, but I am failing to find how to get the second build step to output the resource files that the first build step uses.

The only key difference between the solutions that I can identify is that the first one contains the following `\App.Api\Properties\PublishProfiles\VSTS-InPlacePublish.pubxml` file, while the second does not:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>vsts-publish</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

How do I modify the second build step parameters to output the resources in the build artefact?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually got this working by adding the `/p:IncludeAllContentForPackageToOneFolder=true` flag to the build step.

Also needed to set the `resx` files' `Build Action` property to `Content`.